# PySpark - Update Nested Array of Objects in dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

Struggling to figure out the right sequence of requests to update a nested array of objects in a dataframe with PySpark. One source of data thought it would be funny to create the same names but with difference cases which causes issues. I am trying to merge (concat_ws) the two fields

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

inputString = '[{"a": 1, "b": [{"f": 1, "F": null}, {"f": 2, "F": 2}, {"f": null, "F": 3}]}]'

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    data=[(1,inputString)],
    schema=StructType([
        StructField("id", StringType()),
        StructField("field", StringType())
    ])
)
_schema = ArrayType(spark.read.json(df.select(F.col('field')).rdd.map(lambda row: row.field)).schema)
df = df.withColumn('formatted', F.from_json(F.col('field'), _schema))
```

From here, I am trying to update the objects in array `b` with a simple `F.concat_ws(',', b.F, b.f)` however I seemingly can only get the updated fields returned. I need the entire json object returned.

Here's what I've tried:

```py
display(
    df.withColumn(
        'formatted',
        F.transform(
            F.col('formatted'),
            lambda _field: F.transform(
                _field['b'],
                lambda _array_field: _array_field.withField(
                    'sampleMerge',
                    F.concat(F.col('formatted.b.F').cast(StringType()), F.col('formatted.b.f').cast(StringType()))
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

However, this returns the field as just the array, and merging all objects into one:

```
[
    [
        {"F":null,"f":1,"sampleMerge":"[[null, 2, 3]][[1, 2, null]]"},
        {"F":2,"f":2,"sampleMerge":"[[null, 2, 3]][[1, 2, null]]"},
        {"F":3,"f":null,"sampleMerge":"[[null, 2, 3]][[1, 2, null]]"}
    ]
]
```

There are two issues I cannot figure out

1. How to get the rest of the object returned (i.e. JSON key `a`)
2. How to only merge fields within a given object.

Expected output:

```
[
    {
        "a":1,
        "b":[
            {
                "f":1,
                "F":null,
                "sampleMerge": "1"
            },
            {
                "f":2,
                "F":2,
                "sampleMerge": "2,2"
            },
            {
                "f":null,
                "F":3,
                "sampleMerge": "3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Any help from you smarter people than I would be appreciated. Also open to dealing with case-different keys in any other way as long as the two fields end up merged into a single (second part of this will be dropping the two case-different keys).

I should add that I cannot just enable case-sensitivity in Spark - while that solves the immediate problem in Spark, it just kicks the can down the road to SQL and trying to load the data.

**EDIT/Update**
Figured out getting the `concat_ws` working within a given object - obvious now. Need to use the lambda field reference:

```py
display(
    df.withColumn(
        'formatted',
        F.transform(
            F.col('formatted'),
            lambda _field: F.transform(
                _field['b'],
                lambda _array_field: _array_field.withField(
                    'sampleMerge',
                    F.lit(F.concat_ws(',',_array_field['f'],_array_field['F']))
                    #F.concat(F.col(_array_field['F']).cast(StringType()), F.col(_array_field['f']).cast(StringType()))
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Still not returning the full object though, only the array within `b`